# Menu button missing

Tags: menu

The menu button on my launcher is missing. However i can search for any application using the HUD button.

How do i rectify this? Any ideas.

Also it might help to know that I am running Ubuntu 16.04.3.
[Here is a screen shot of my desktop notice there is no button for menu instead there is a trash button at it's location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qssNS.jpg)

[Here you will see a button which looks somewhat like :: It displays all the applications installed on the computer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0k7QL.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Would you mind adding a screenshot? Press the [<Print Screen>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Print_screen) button, [edit] your question and add it using the [formatting tools](https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting).

Comment: Can you do a screen shot and what you're expecting to see and where you were expecting to see it ?

Comment: I added the pic.